# How vectorizer fit_transform work in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand the following code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 

vectorizer = CountVectorizer() 

corpus = ['This is the first document.','This is the second second document.','And the third one.','Is this the first document?'] 

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

When I try to print X to see what will be return, I got this result :

```
(0, 1)  1

(0, 2)  1

(0, 6)  1

(0, 3)  1

(0, 8)  1

(1, 5)  2

(1, 1)  1

(1, 6)  1

(1, 3)  1

(1, 8)  1

(2, 4)  1

(2, 7)  1

(2, 0)  1

(2, 6)  1

(3, 1)  1

(3, 2)  1

(3, 6)  1

(3, 3)  1

(3, 8)  1
```

However, I don't understand the meaning of this result ?

Comment: Thats the result of sparse matrix. Convert it to dense using X.toarray() and then print

Comment: but what is the meaning of the number for example:" (3,6) 1 "in here. Could you explain me in detail ?

Comment: In a sparse matrix, most of the entries are zero and hence not stored to save memory. The numbers in bracket are the index of the value in the matrix (row, column) and 1 is the value (The number of times a term appeared in the document represented by the row of the matrix).

Comment: if "1" is the number of times a term appreared in the document, so why in the first document, "the" appeared 2 times but all the location (from (0,1) to (0.8) have the same value 1 ?

Comment: Maybe 'the' is a stop word and not included in the learnt vocabulary. Please check the actual vocabulary words for which the indices are used here by printing the `vectorizer.get_feature_names()`

Comment: I see, it show the list of words which indice and actually "second" appeared twice. Thanks you very much, you really save my day :)

Answer (score 4):

As @Himanshu writes, this is a "(sentence_index, feature_index) count"

Here, the count part is the "number of times a word appears in a document"

For example,

> (0, 1)  1
>
> (0, 2)  1
>
> (0, 6)  1
>
> (0, 3)  1
>
> (0, 8)  1
>
> **(1, 5)  2**  Only for this example, the count "2" tells that the word "and" appears twice in this document/sentence
>
> (1, 1)  1
>
> (1, 6)  1
>
> (1, 3)  1
>
> (1, 8)  1
>
> (2, 4)  1
>
> (2, 7)  1
>
> (2, 0)  1
>
> (2, 6)  1
>
> (3, 1)  1
>
> (3, 2)  1
>
> (3, 6)  1
>
> (3, 3)  1
>
> (3, 8)  1

Let's change the corpus in your code. Basically, I added the word "second" twice in the second sentence of the corpus list.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 

vectorizer = CountVectorizer() 

corpus = ['This is the first document.','This is the second second second second document.','And the third one.','Is this the first document?'] 

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

> (0, 1)  1
>
> (0, 2)  1
>
> (0, 6)  1
>
> (0, 3)  1
>
> (0, 8)  1
>
> **(1, 5)  4**  for the modified corpus, the count "4" tells that the word "second" appears four times in this document/sentence
>
> (1, 1)  1
>
> (1, 6)  1
>
> (1, 3)  1
>
> (1, 8)  1
>
> (2, 4)  1
>
> (2, 7)  1
>
> (2, 0)  1
>
> (2, 6)  1
>
> (3, 1)  1
>
> (3, 2)  1
>
> (3, 6)  1
>
> (3, 3)  1
>
> (3, 8)  1

Answer (score 3):

You can interpret this as "(sentence_index, feature_index) count"

As there are 3 sentence: it starts from 0 and ends at 2

feature index is word index which u can get from vectorizer.vocabulary_

-> vocabulary_ a dictionary {word:feature_index,...}

so for the example (0, 1)  1

```
-> 0 : row[the sentence index]

-> 1 : get feature index(i.e. the word) from vectorizer.vocabulary_[1]

-> 1 : count/tfidf (as you have used a count vectorizer, it will give you count)
```

instead of count vectorizer, if you use tfidf vectorizer[see here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) it will give u tfidf values. 
I hope I made it clear

Answer (score -2):

It transforms text to numbers. So with other functions you will be able to count how many times each word existed in the given data set. Im new to programming so maybe there are other fields to use as well.